# Carregar perfil do chrome no selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando carregar meu perfil do Chrome mas não consigo, o que está faltando?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


    class Teste:


        def __init__(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            chrome_options = Options()
            chrome_options.add_argument("C:/Users/e5512459/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")
            brs = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/e5512459/PycharmProjects/wpp/chromedriver.exe",
                                   chrome_options=chrome_options)

        def abrir(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")


    wpp = Teste()
    wpp.abrir()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma serie de coisa que precisa ser feito.

1. Você esta criando dois drivers e passando as `Options` no segundo e acessando o site no primeiro.
2. Faltou dizer qual o argumento  seria usado no `addargument` nesse caso é o `user-data-dir`
3. Outra coisa quando passar o diretório que está as informações do usuário deve ser ate a pasta User Data

No Final seu código ficara assim.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class Teste():
    def __init__(self):

        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/e5512459/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
        self.brs = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/e5512459/PycharmProjects/wpp/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)


    def abrir(self):
        driver = self.brs
        driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")


wpp = Teste()
wpp.abrir()
```

Comment: mesmo assim ele ainda não carrega o perfil, inicia como um perfil novo

Comment: Mudei o código um pouco, acredito que agora vai

Comment: @Filipe.C agora o código esta funcionando

Comment: Obrigado! resolveu aqui.